# Google APIs getting errors on command bazel build //

Tags: google-api, bazel

Trying to build [Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis) for dart.
After installing Bazel 0.28.0 successfully the next step is to execute the command `bazel build //...` but I am getting errors.

Output: `bazel build //...` :

```
    ERROR: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/nodejs/nodejs_gapic_pkg.bzl:62:17: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/nodejs/nodejs_gapic_pkg.bzl", line 60
                rule(attrs = {"deps": attr.label_list...)}, <2 more arguments>)
        File "/home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/nodejs/nodejs_gapic_pkg.bzl", line 62, in rule
                attr.label_list(allow_files = True, mandatory = Tr..., ...)
'non_empty' is no longer supported. use allow_empty instead. You can use --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false to temporarily disable this check.
ERROR: error loading package 'google/api/experimental': in /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_googleapis_imports/imports.bzl: Extension file 'rules_gapic/nodejs/nodejs_gapic_pkg.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.673s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (14 packages loaded)
    currently loading: google/api/experimental ... (18 packages)
```

In the bottom it suggesting to use `--incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false`

Output `$ bazel build //...  --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false` :

```
    INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'io_grpc_grpc_java' which is a http_archive (rule definition at /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:237:16):
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_gax_java/repositories.bzl:122:5
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_gax_java/repositories.bzl:58:5
 - /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/WORKSPACE:58:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'io_grpc_grpc_java':
   java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/archive/v1.21.0.zip] to /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/v1.21.0.zip: connect timed out
ERROR: no such package '@io_grpc_grpc_java//': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/archive/v1.21.0.zip] to /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/v1.21.0.zip: connect timed out
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.335s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (44 packages loaded)
    currently loading: google/api ... (79 packages)
```

Running `bazel build //... --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false` again return new error:

```
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in cel_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigtableadmin_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigtable_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in asset_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in automl_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigquerydatatransfer_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigquerystorage_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dataproc_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dialogflow_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in iot_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in kms_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in language_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in oslogin_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in redis_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in scheduler_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in securitycenter_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in speech_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in tasks_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in texttospeech_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in video_intelligence_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in vision_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in websecurityscanner_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in container_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in datastore_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in debugger_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in clouderrorreporting_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in trace_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in containeranalysis_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in library_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in firestore_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in iamcredentials_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in logging_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in monitoring_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dlp_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in pubsub_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_admin_database_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_admin_instance_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_java_grpc
ERROR: /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/google/longrunning/BUILD.bazel:107:1: in _generate_cc rule //google/longrunning:_longrunning_cc_grpc_grpc_codegen: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/google/longrunning/BUILD.bazel", line 107
                _generate_cc(name = '_longrunning_cc_grpc_grpc_codegen')
        File "/home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_github_grpc_grpc/bazel/generate_cc.bzl", line 44, in generate_cc_impl
                [f for src in ctx.attr.srcs for f in src.proto.check_deps_sources]
type 'depset' is not iterable. Use the `to_list()` method to get a list. Use --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false to temporarily disable this check.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//google/longrunning:_longrunning_cc_grpc_grpc_codegen' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//google/longrunning:_longrunning_cc_grpc_grpc_codegen' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.381s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

In the bottom it suggesting this time to add `--incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false`

Output `$ bazel build //... --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false --incompatible_depset_is_not_iterable=false` :

```
    DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dialogflow_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in tasks_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in scheduler_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in iot_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in automl_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in websecurityscanner_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in securitycenter_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_admin_instance_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigtable_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dlp_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigtableadmin_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in datastore_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in firestore_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in spanner_admin_database_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in texttospeech_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in oslogin_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in vision_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in video_intelligence_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in language_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in speech_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in redis_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in asset_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in dataproc_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in kms_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigquerydatatransfer_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in bigquerystorage_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in pubsub_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in iamcredentials_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in monitoring_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in trace_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in debugger_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in library_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in clouderrorreporting_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in container_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in cel_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in containeranalysis_java_grpc
DEBUG: /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/io_grpc_grpc_java/java_grpc_library.bzl:187:9: Multiple values in 'deps' is deprecated in logging_java_grpc
INFO: SHA256 (https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.1.30.tar.gz) = a604edf85d5dfc28e6ff3016dad3954c50b93db69afc42295178b4fdf42e026c
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking whether to enable runpaths... yes
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for bison version... invalid
configure: WARNING: This bison version is not supported for regeneration of the Zend/PHP parsers (found: none, min: 204, excluded: ).
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for re2c... no
checking whether to enable computed goto gcc extension with re2c... no
checking whether to force non-PIC code in shared modules... no
checking whether /dev/urandom exists... yes
checking whether /dev/arandom exists... no
checking for global register variables support... yes
checking for pthreads_cflags... -pthread
checking for pthreads_lib... pthread

Configuring SAPI modules
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS... no
checking for setproctitle... no
checking sys/pstat.h usability... no
checking sys/pstat.h presence... no
checking for sys/pstat.h... no
checking for PS_STRINGS... no
checking for CLI build... yes
checking for embedded SAPI library support... no
checking for FPM build... no
checking for LiteSpeed support... no
checking for phpdbg support... yes
checking for phpdbg web SAPI support... no
checking for phpdbg debug build... no
checking whether termios.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... no
checking whether sys/ioctl.h defines TIOCGWINSZ... yes
checking for CGI build... yes
checking for socklen_t in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for sun_len in sys/un.h... no
checking whether cross-process locking is required by accept()... no
checking for chosen SAPI module... none
checking for executable SAPI binaries...  cli phpdbg cgi

Running system checks
checking for sendmail... no
checking whether system uses EBCDIC... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking whether writing to stdout works... This is the test message -- yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for socketpair... yes
checking for htonl... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for gethostbyaddr... yes
checking for yp_get_default_domain... no
checking for __yp_get_default_domain... no
checking for yp_get_default_domain in -lnsl... yes
checking for dlopen... no
checking for __dlopen... no
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for inet_aton... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h... no
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for alloca.h... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for arpa/nameser.h... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking for crypt.h... yes
checking for dns.h... no
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for grp.h... yes
checking for ieeefp.h... no
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for monetary.h... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for pwd.h... yes
checking for resolv.h... yes
checking for signal.h... yes

INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'php_cs_fixer' which is a http_file (rule definition at /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl:314:13):
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/php/php_gapic_repositories.bzl:85:5
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/php/php_gapic_repositories.bzl:53:5
 - /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/WORKSPACE:154:1
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'php_cs_fixer':
   java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.9.1/php-cs-fixer.phar] to /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/php_cs_fixer/file/downloaded: connect timed out
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'php' which is a php (rule definition at /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/php/php_gapic_repositories.bzl:45:7):
 - /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/WORKSPACE:149:1
INFO: Call stack for the definition of repository 'org_golang_google_api' which is a go_repository (rule definition at /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/bazel_gazelle/internal/go_repository.bzl:122:17):
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/go/go_gapic_repositories.bzl:47:5
 - /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/com_google_api_codegen/rules_gapic/go/go_gapic_repositories.bzl:27:9
 - /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/WORKSPACE:113:1
ERROR: /home/compName/Documents/programing/git/googleapis/google/cloud/language/v1/BUILD.bazel:151:1: //google/cloud/language/v1:language_php_gapic_srcjar depends on @php_cs_fixer//file:file in repository @php_cs_fixer which failed to fetch. no such package '@php_cs_fixer//file': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.9.1/php-cs-fixer.phar] to /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/php_cs_fixer/file/downloaded: connect timed out
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:gapic-cloud-build' failed; build aborted: no such package '@php_cs_fixer//file': java.io.IOException: Error downloading [https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.9.1/php-cs-fixer.phar] to /home/compName/.cache/bazel/_bazel_compName/f637105f0b92ecbc6cfa014e9afed99a/external/php_cs_fixer/file/downloaded: connect timed out
INFO: Elapsed time: 16.718s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (290 packages loaded, 13170 targets configured)
    Fetching @go_googleapis; Cloning 41d72d444fbe445f4da89e13be02078734fb7875 of https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis 11s
```

Comment: The last error says `connect timed out`, so looks like it's a network issue?